# How to do SFDX source deploy to non-scratch org with destructive changes

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have a question around SFDX source deploy to non-scratch org, with destructive changes using CI/CD pipeline:

```
## Authenticate with your playground or sandbox environment
$ sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i $CONSUMER_KEY -f assets/server.key -r $SF_TARGET_URL -u $USERNAME -a TARGETOrg

## Deploy source to sandbox org (This is with source code, all files, etc)    
$ sfdx force:source:deploy -l $TESTLEVEL -g -u TARGETOrg -w 180 -x ./manifest/package.xml
```

`force:source:deploy` does not consider destructive changes so delete metadata. 
I can use:
`$ sfdx force:source:delete -g -u TARGETOrg -m ./manifest/destructivechanges.xml`
and 
`$ sfdx force:source:delete -g -u TARGETOrg -m ./manifest/destructiveChangesPre.xml`

before and after `force:source:deploy`. But these would be three different transactions. If something goes wrong in the deploy command, the next statement won't execute. This is something which is not correct.

I don't want to do `mdapi` commands to deploy. How is this possible using `source:deploy`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use destructive changes with force:source:deploy. Instead, you would need to use Unlocked Packages. Create a package version that includes all the metadata, then create a new version with the items to be deleted removed from the package. Install the first package, which then associates the contents with the unpackaged metadata, then install the new version with --upgradetype Delete to cause the items to be deleted. A package install counts as a single transaction (for creating new elements, updating existing elements, and deleting old elements), thus providing you with the atomic transactions you're looking for.

Comment: When you say "Create a package version that includes all the metadata, then create a new version with the items to delete", do you really mean "...then create a new version with items _deleted from the new version of the package_"

Comment: @BrianMiller Yes, that is clearer. I'll revise :p

Comment: since API 53.0 you can use `--postdestructivechanges` or `--predestructivechanges` with the `sfdx force:source:deploy` command to pass a destructivechanges file

Answer (score 1):

This feature is released:

> NEW: Delete metadata components in your org at the same time you run
> force:source:deploy --manifest with the new --predestructivechanges
> and --postdestructivechanges parameters. Similar to how the --manifest
> parameter works, set the new parameters to a manifest file. But rather
> than deploy the components in the file, the command deletes them from
> your org. Depending on the parameter, the delete executes either
> before (pre) or after (post) the deploy.
>
> For example, this command deletes the components in the
> preDestruct.xml manifest file before you deploy the components in the
> package.xml file:
>
> ```
> sfdx force:source:deploy -x package.xml --predestructivechanges preDestruct.xml
> ```

https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/sfdx/README.md#71240-oct-28-2021